# Not able to access data from Userdefaults - Swfit

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I am accessing user default value as:

```
let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: identifier)
```

when I see the value in data it is visible as:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOjI8.png

type of `data` is

```
 po type(of: data)
 Swift.Optional<Any> . //Output
```

How can I access `pageNumber`?

Answer (score 1):

since data is a dictionary in order to have access to `pageNumber` you need to cast data as a `Dictionary`

```
guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: identifier) as? [String: Any] else { //fallback here if you need return }
let pageNumber = data["pageNumber"] as? Int ?? 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `dictionary(forKey:)` method on `UserDefaults` instance to directly fetch a `dictionary` from `UserDefaults`.

The `dictionary` returned is of type `[String:Any]?`

```
if let dict = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: identifier) {
    let pageNumber = dict["pageNumber"] as? Int 
}
```

**Note:** `pageNumber` is of type `Int?`. `Unwrap` it to use further.